# Divide a table into two parts in one column

Tags: html, datatables

I'm using tables for my website layout, and I want to divide one table into two, but having both the tables in the same column. (Specifically, one being 300px and the other being 200). I cannot figure out how to do this.
Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
    <style>
.menuleft {
background:white;
width:17%;
height:500px;
padding: 10px;
border-radius:12px 0px 0px 12px;
border:1px dashed pink;
}

.menuright {
background:white;
width:17%;
height:500px;
padding: 10px;
border-radius:0px 12px 12px 0px;
border:1px dashed pink;
}

.maintable {
background:white;
border: 1px dashed pink;
padding: 10px;
height:500px;
width:60%;
}
</style>

    <tr>
               <td colspan = "2" height="100px">
                 title
                </td>
             </tr>
        <tr valign="top" class="main">
                <td class="menuleft">
                  
                </td>
                    
                <td class="maintable">
                   
                </td>
                    
                <td class="menuright">
                   
                </td>
             </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your description is not really clear, but as far as I understand if you want to divide rows or columns you simply use colspan and rowspan.
[check this link for more infos](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_table_colspan_rowspan.asp)